# Python Setup On Windows

Tags: python, django, installation

Please a Step by Step on Setting Up Python and Installing Django and Running Environment variable

i installed python proper added Path and Installed Django but still the my Django is not running properly, it shows Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check [ask], then [edit] your question and describe exactly what you did and what happened. There are already plenty of tutorials and instructions for installing Django. Nobody wants to type yet another one for you. These tutorials probably work and you did something wrong. It's up to you to show what you did so that people can help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you haven't installed python correctly what i recommend is to check if you have python already installed.

1. Open a command prompt type "cmd" on windows search.    Type
   "python --version" in the command prompt and press Enter. It should
   display the installed Python version.

If not, double-check your installation.

2. or the problem can be in the Configure Environment Variables as i
   had this     problem so many times when I'm trying to use PHP on a
   new pc.
   you can fix that by Right-click on the "This PC" or "My
   Computer" icon and     select "Properties."    Click on "Advanced
   system settings" on the left sidebar.    In the System Properties
   window, click on the "Environment Variables"     button.    In the
   "User variables" section, select the "Path" variable and click on "Edit."    Click on "New" and add the path to your Python
   installation directory (e.g.,     C:\PythonXX) ..    Click "OK" to
   save the changes.

   I hope this answer provides some assistance,
   despite my limited experience.

Comment: Or you can install Anaconda. or Activestate python, or install WSL and run Ubuntu with python pre installed